# What do "BS" and "BH" mean in the 现代汉语词典?

Tags: dictionary

**What are the meanings of *BS* and *BH* as seen in the screenshot below?**

[image: example of BS and BH used in 现代汉语词典]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally thought my guess was just a wild stab, but after checking the 现代汉语词典 website, it didn't look as wild as I had thought.
I think BS stands for "bu shou" (radical), and BH stands for "bi hua" (strokes). In your example, 你·has five strokes, not counting the two in the radical.

Please check other entries to verify this. If my guess is correct, 她 should read: BS:女  BH:3

Comment: I think you got it right.